# Show message inside a modal window

Tags: extjs, modal-dialog, window

Here is my modal window:

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        modal: true,
        closeAction: 'destroy',
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
        },
        title:'Info',
        listeners: {
            close: function(panel, eOpts) {
                Ext.getBody().removeCls('darkMask');
            }
        }
    })
```

The problem is that I want to show some message inside the model body, any suggestions how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Usualy I use html property for this. It's can contains any HTML, that will be out to the window body:

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        modal: true,
        closeAction: 'destroy',
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
        },
        title:'Info',
        html: '<h1>The message</h1> <p>Here some <b>text</b></p>',
        listeners: {
            close: function(panel, eOpts) {
                Ext.getBody().removeCls('darkMask');
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar in a panel to display an error that in some cases occurs.

I used a container with layout fit in which there were a textarea.

maybe there are other solutions, but if you set some css to the textarea it will be nice also in the design and the text can be easly changed with a setValue